# How to calculate percentage in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

I have this google-doc: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Avl3X68NxHC-dFY2YWgzTnRVZm1xaWlBTFl6TU9NTkE&usp=sharing

Now I am trying to calculate the average (`=average()`) of the percentages of my tasks.
But I want to have only the average percentage of all tasks, where the "Projektaufgabe" is set "n".

How can I do that?

Comment: I would suggest that you copy a small sample set of data here so we can see what you're looking at without having to go off-site to look at it. Off the top of my head, I have a feeling you want to look at `AVERAGEIF()`.

Comment: From my understanding this can be resolved as of now with the same function that Excel uses AVERAGEIF as that function is available with the latest [Google Spreadsheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256529?hl=en).

Answer (score 1):

Excel would use [`averageif()`](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/averageif.php), but according to [this link](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/L_CKN1AWM34), a Google spreadsheet does not have such a function.

But you can instead use [`filter()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197)

```
=average(filter(c3:c44;b3:b44="n"))
```